# Can I select by class in a tag hierarchy in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: beautifulsoup

```
<div class="menu-drop-main">
   <ul class="menu-drop-list">
      <li><a href="/list.html?cat=1316,16831" title="男士面部护肤">男士面部护肤</a></li>
      <li><a href="/list.html?cat=1316,16832" title="美妆工具">美妆工具</a></li>
      <li><a href="/list.html?cat=1316,1381" title="面部护肤">面部护肤</a></li>
      <li><a href="/list.html?cat=1316,1387" title="香水彩妆">香水彩妆</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

If I want to use 'select' instead of 'find', can I get a list of the 4 'li' tags?

```
tags = soup.select('div ul .menu-drop-main')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `soup.select('.menu-drop-main li')`. That will select all `<li>` tags under tag with `class="menu-drop-main"`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<div class="menu-drop-main">
   <ul class="menu-drop-list">
      <li><a href="/list.html?cat=1316,16831" title="男士面部护肤">男士面部护肤</a></li>
      <li><a href="/list.html?cat=1316,16832" title="美妆工具">美妆工具</a></li>
      <li><a href="/list.html?cat=1316,1381" title="面部护肤">面部护肤</a></li>
      <li><a href="/list.html?cat=1316,1387" title="香水彩妆">香水彩妆</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
print(*soup.select(".menu-drop-main li"), sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```html
<li><a href="/list.html?cat=1316,16831" title="男士面部护肤">男士面部护肤</a></li>
<li><a href="/list.html?cat=1316,16832" title="美妆工具">美妆工具</a></li>
<li><a href="/list.html?cat=1316,1381" title="面部护肤">面部护肤</a></li>
<li><a href="/list.html?cat=1316,1387" title="香水彩妆">香水彩妆</a></li>
```